# How can I simplify this electric circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

I am having trouble simplifying this electric circuit. Should I neglect R1 in the simplification or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to the charges when a resistor is short-circuited?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619951/)